# tcpdump on iOS / Jailbreak

Tags: objective-c, ios, jailbreak, libpcap, tcpdump

Is there an iOS-compatible Objective-C-port of the `tcpdump` C-sources or a working `tcpdump`binary for iOS? And if so, does it capture the traffic from *all* network devices? Or does it capture only an Ethernet device? Is there `libpcap` for iOS? I am aware, that this requires a jailbroken Phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes to both:

http://planet-iphones.com/cydia/id/tcpdump

http://planet-iphones.com/cydia/id/libpcap

However I don't understand why you want an Objective-C port?

Comment: i asked for a objective-c port because i wanted to build it into a gui app. and calling plain c code from obj-c code would halt the event loop, wouln't it? what would actually be better practice: call the commandline tool and intercept its output or have tcpdump built into the gui app?

Comment: on the iPhone 4 of a friend, tcpdump does not show up in the repository. i do no longer have access to his phone, so i can not check if the executable (manually downloaded) can be ran on his device. do you know, whether the binary is compatible with iPhone 4 / 5 CPU Architecture?

Comment: @Sebastian My iPhone 4 Cydia shows `tcpdump` within search, however I cannot access the package over 3G and am not near a usable Wifi.  So it looks like it's supported (and there is no reason to suppose the iPhone 4 CPU does not support everything).

Comment: @Sebastian, unless I'm misunderstanding you, **no**, calling C code from Objective-C doesn't halt the event loop.  Lots of the normal, public iOS APIs are actually C APIs.  They don't halt the event loop.  I can understand why you don't want to have to run a command line process and capture output, but C vs. Objective-C shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. i will get access to a phone next week and then try it out.